# Facebook getLoginStatus was not getting any response

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
      <script>
        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
          FB.init({
            appId      : '261852174300349',
            status     : true, 
            cookie     : true,
            xfbml      : true,
            oauth      : true,
          });
        };
        (function(d){
           var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
           js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
           js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
           d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
         }(document));

       //LOGIN FUNCTION 
       function login() {
           FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
                console.log(response)
            });

     }
      </script>
      <div onclick="login();">Login with Facebook</div>
```

As per facebook document to check user is already login or not we can use `FB.getLoginStatus` get the user is log in or not but in my cause i can"t able to get any response

Comment: why not use getLoginStatus right after FB.init? there is FB.login for the login instead.

Comment: i tried but no response from facebook

Answer (score 0):

try this instead. It will call the login function right after being initialized. In your current code

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
      <script>
        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
          FB.init({
            appId      : '261852174300349',
            status     : true, 
            cookie     : true,
            xfbml      : true,
            oauth      : true,
          });
//LOGIN FUNCTION 
           function login() {
               FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
                    console.log(response)
                });

         }
        };
        (function(d){
           var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
           js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
           js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
           d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
         }(document));


      </script>
      <div onclick="login();">Login with Facebook</div>
```